# how to update column dataframe data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Usually, I use a list I simplify the timestamp by finding the difference between two successive values like this:

```
 x=[ 1552154111, 1552154115, 1552154117, 1552154120, 1552154125 
    ,1552154127, 1552154134, 1552154137]
    List_time = []
    for i in x:
        List_time.append((i + 1) - x[0])
    print(List_time)
[1, 5, 7, 10, 15, 17, 24, 27]
```

I need to have the same result by using the dataframe, which looks like this:

```
print(df['Timestamp'])

0         1552154111
1         1552154115
2         1552154117
3         1552154120
4         1552154125
5         1552154127
6         1552154134
7         1552154137
```

I need to replace the currect timestamp column with the expected difference. I don't know how to do that. It is the first I use a dataframe.

How could I do that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it with :

```
first_value = df.loc[0]
new_row = df.apply(lambda x: x + 1 - first_value)
```

`first_value` represents `x[0]`.

Usually, you can achieve element-wise operations on pandas Series with [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: thank you but, it gives me this error:     lambda x: op(x, rvalues))
TypeError: ("Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly", 'occurred at index Timestamp')

Comment: What does `first_value` return? What is `type(first_value)`? Maybe `df.loc[0]` does not access your first line

Comment: print(first_value)   and  print(df['Timestamp'].loc[0])   give me both 1552154111

Comment: Is the type of `first_value` an int? Is it the same for _all_ the entries in the `Timestamp` column?

Answer (score 2):

A potential solution that does not involve a `df.apply(lambda)` loop:

```
df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'] - df['Timestamp'].iloc[0] + 1
```